# Passing ListArray<Object> from Servlet to JSP working in Windows but failing in Linux

Tags: java, linux, jsp, servlets

A method of passing a ListArray from my Servlet to a JSP page which works fine in my Windows dev env is failing in my Linux env.

The ListArray contains a set of global values, so I declare it immediately inside the Servlet class and populate it in the Init method.

In both the doGet and doPost methods, I assign it to an attribute on the request object:

```
    request.setAttribute("servers", servers);
    request.getRequestDispatcher(page).forward(request, response);
```

In the .jsp I retrieve it and process it:

```
<%

    ArrayList<Server> servers = (ArrayList<Server>) request.getAttribute("servers");    

for(Server server : servers){

            out.print("<p><form method='post' action='Controller' encType='multipart/form-data'><input type='hidden' name='action' value='control'/>");
            out.print("<input type='hidden' name='name' value='"
                    + server.getName() + "'/>");
            out.print("<input type='hidden' name='url' value='"
                    + server.getUrl() + "'/>");
            out.print("<input type='hidden' name='local' value='"
                    + server.getLocation() + "'/>");
            out.print("<input type='hidden' name='port' value='"
                    + server.getPort() + "'/>");
            out.print("<input type='submit' value='Select'/><span class='label'> "
                    + server.getName() + " </span></form><p>"); 

}
    %>
```

First, yes *I know scriptlets are deprecated*, learning JSTL is on the list of things to do this quarter.

In Windows, this successfully processes the Server objects into a tidy list. In Linux it fails like so:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 82

79:     
80:     ArrayList<Server> servers = (ArrayList<Server>) request.getAttribute("servers");        
81:         
82: for(Server server : servers){
83:             
84:             out.print("<p><form method='post' action='Controller' encType='multipart/form-data'><input type='hidden' name='action' value='control'/>");
85:             out.print("<input type='hidden' name='name' value='"


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:151)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.55 logs.
```

I'm running Java 1.7.0_07 in both env.

Any thoughts on why this method of passing the arraylist would be failing in Linux?

Comment: Commenting out the declaration of the ArrayList in the JSP and replacing it with a standard "ArrayList<Server> servers = new ArrayList<Server>(); killed the error message, but of course now it's just processing an empty list. This suggests that as far as Linux is concerned I've not yet created an ArrayList at all when I do it this way: ArrayList<Server> servers = (ArrayList<Server>) request.getAttribute("servers");

Comment: You are just guessing.  And you will only solve the problem that way if you "get lucky".  Please follow the strategy I suggested in my Answer.  Look at the code, and work out what is actually `null`.

Comment: No, what I am doing is experimenting to eliminate variables and narrowing the scope of the problem. At this point I know that I've got a valid ListArray in the servlet, and that the jsp is OK with an *empty* ListArray, but the method I'm using to collect the ListArray from the request object and assign it to a new ListArray in the JSP is not creating anything that Java recognizes as actually being a ListArray. I was concerned that the problem was related to *how I was creating* the ListArray in  the servlet, but this is not the case; the problem is in transmission.

Answer (score 1):

> Any thoughts on why this method of passing the arraylist would be failing in Linux?

One possibility is that the arraylist is `null` or one of its elements or one of its elements' fields is `null`.  I suspect that this is happening in the servlet ... before you forward the request.

But speculating on this isn't going to help you solve your problem.  What you need to do is:

- Compare the stacktrace with the Java line numbers in the compiled JSP code.
- Figure out what Java code is giving the exception.
- Apply some logical inference to the problem, to work out *where* the `null` is ... and (ultimately) where it comes from.

If logical inference doesn't work, add some traceprints to figure out where the `null` is coming from.

Unfortunately, we don't have the evidence to do this for you.

But the good news is that you should be able to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: Narrowed the problem down by creating and testing the ListArray in the servlet *immediately before* assigning it to the attribute and attaching it to the response, so at that point I knew that the problem was something to do with how it was being sent/received, since it was clearly not null. At this point, I've just rewritten the .jsp to generate the ListArray itself, which I didn't want to do.